# Grab and list URLs of multiple sheets/tab

Tags: google-sheets

Not sure if this can be done by plugging in a formula in a cell and dragging down, or if it needs a script.

I'm initially inclined to just use a formula since I can use `INDIRECT` to reference to my sheets, but I don't know if a function exists that can grab a URL from the referenced sheet or if I need to write a script to do so.

Any help pointing me to a direction or even an actual solution would be most invaluable since I'm dealing with 200+ sheets here, and going to each sheet, to grab the url and then going back to my master sheet to paste them is very cumbersome and can become confusing.

EDIT:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()&"!A1")
```

since it isn't clear for others here where my roadblock is, this is where I'm at. I have no idea how or if it is at all possible through a formula to grab a URL, or if I need a script.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I've already mentioned that I can reference to my sheets using `INDIRECT` and explained my specific roadblock.

nonetheless,  I edited my post to show where I'm at

Comment: I don't see the problem. Your formula works, and it is dynamic, so just start in row 1 and copy it down 200+ rows. BUT, when you say "200+ sheets", do you mean one spreadsheet with 200 sheets, or 200 spreadsheets? If you are referring to 200 spreadsheets, then 1) a script is the best approach (and is easy to do), and 2) are all the spreadsheets in the same folder/sub-folders and do you have access to them all? You've specifically referred to a URL that exists in cell A1 of sheet1 of each "sheet" - is this a run-of-the-mill URL, or the URL required to open a specific spreadsheet/sheet?